# Why did Stuart and Sons invent a 102-key piano?

Tags: piano, history

Stuart and Sons have invented a huge 102-key grand piano.  What is the reason behind this?

Comment: https://www.npr.org/2011/01/18/132945634/musical-innovation-a-grander-grand-piano This article is found immediately with Google and gives the designer's own words on the reason. How can anyone here do better?

Comment: Most likely because the answer is easily found with the minimum of Googling? We do like to think that questions are researched by the OP prior to being asked here. Probably even more information that may be forthcoming from contributors on this site can be gleaned by use of such methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maker has said in an [interview](https://www.npr.org/2011/01/18/132945634/musical-innovation-a-grander-grand-piano) (link from replete’s comment):

> I'd hate to go back to the 88-key piano... I couldn't stand it. It's too limited.

Which suggests he values having the extra notes.

He also said:

> I'm all for innovation in the modern piano. To me, the piano is a pinnacle of human achievement. So it seems right and proper that it should continue to develop.

Which clarifies he is in favor of finding ways to expand the capabilities of the piano in general.

Note that while organs and synthesizers don’t always have keyboards with as many keys, they generally can both be played higher and lower than typical pianos, so it’s not like an 88 key piano has all the notes we would want to play or hear.

Comment: It pretty much does, though. The notes added by super-sized pianos like the Bösendorfer are musically almost worthless; the point of having them is that they provide richer resonance to the sound of the standard notes.

Comment: If they add a benefit at all, which you concede, then they aren't worthless, are they